# WSO2 API Manager - Token restrictions 20KPerToken

Tags: validation, wso2, token, wso2-api-manager, restrictions

Can I limit token to make 20K per token validity requests. My use case is:
give to user token with year validity and 20K per token limitations.

Thank you in advance for any help!

EDIT:
When I'm adding application limit 20PerYear and generate token with validity -1, it's not working, because I can execute as many requests as I want, not only 20.

Use case: I want to sell to client 20K requests to my API not depending on time. Maybe WSO2 have another solutions for my use case?

UPDATE:

1) I added 5PerAllTime Application Tier:
[image: Admin]

2) Select new created application AllTime per token quota as 5PerAllTime
[image: Application]

3) Generate production token for new created application AllTime with validity period -1

2) Add PizzaShackAPI to Application

4) Get a lot menu requests, but any restrictions is not visible :\

What am I doing wrong?

**SOLUTION:**

All working. I am on Windows and I saw in logs that something bad happening with filepaths on Windows, when I'm adding new application tier:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-11-03 10:02:36,113] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver} -  Illegal char <:> at index 2: /D:/taras2/wso2/WSO2AM~1.0/bin/../repository/deployment/server/\executionplans {org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver}
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:173)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doPost(CarbonServlet.java:231)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilter.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CSRFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CSRFPreventionFilter.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CRLFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CRLFPreventionFilter.java:59)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.tenantmgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:48)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1749)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1708)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 2: /D:/taras2/wso2/WSO2AM~1.0/bin/../repository/deployment/server/\executionplans
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:94)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:255)
    at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:84)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.core.internal.util.EventProcessorUtil.validateFilePath(EventProcessorUtil.java:387)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.core.internal.util.EventProcessorConfigurationFilesystemInvoker.save(EventProcessorConfigurationFilesystemInvoker.java:77)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.core.internal.CarbonEventProcessorService.deployExecutionPlan(CarbonEventProcessorService.java:127)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.admin.EventProcessorAdminService.deployExecutionPlan(EventProcessorAdminService.java:53)
    ... 63 more
```

After that error I can see my application tier into select box, but there is no file in system for my tier and limitations not working. So I added this file manually into filepath ${carbon.home}/repository/deployment/server/executionplans.

Example of 20KPerYear new execution plan (named carbon.super_app_20KPerYear.siddhiql):

```
/* Enter a unique ExecutionPlan */
@Plan:name('carbon.super_app_20KPerYear')

/* Enter a unique description for ExecutionPlan */
@Plan:description('Allows 20K request per year')

/* define streams/tables and write queries here ... */

@Import('org.wso2.throttle.processed.request.stream:1.0.0')
define stream RequestStream (messageID string, appKey string, appTier string, subscriptionKey string, apiKey string, apiTier string, subscriptionTier string, resourceKey string, resourceTier string, userId string, apiContext string, apiVersion string, appTenant string, apiTenant string, appId string, apiName string, propertiesMap string);

@Export('org.wso2.throttle.globalThrottle.stream:1.0.0')
define stream GlobalThrottleStream (throttleKey string, isThrottled bool, expiryTimeStamp long);

FROM RequestStream
SELECT messageID, ( appTenant == 'carbon.super' and appTier == '20KPerYear') AS isEligible, appKey AS throttleKey
INSERT INTO EligibilityStream;

FROM EligibilityStream[isEligible==true]#throttler:timeBatch(1 year, 0)
select throttleKey, (count(messageID) >= 20000) as isThrottled, expiryTimeStamp
group by throttleKey 
INSERT ALL EVENTS into ResultStream;

from ResultStream#throttler:emitOnStateChange(throttleKey, isThrottled)
select *
insert into GlobalThrottleStream;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an `Application Level` throttling policy for this. Read more information [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Setting+Throttling+Limits#SettingThrottlingLimits-Application-levelthrottling(applicationdeveloper)).

Update: To limit the number of requests per year, you can set the throttling level to 20kPerYear. To expire tokens after 1 year, you can set `AccessTokenDefaultValidityPeriod` in `identity.xml`.

I just tried this myself with a 20perYear limit to make sure this works fine. After about 21-22 request requests failed with this response.

```
{"fault":{"code":900803,"message":"Message throttled out","description":"You have 
exceeded your quota","nextAccessTime":"2016-Dec-20 00:00:00+0000 UTC"}}
```

Please note that since throttling works in an asynchronous manner, it may not throttle out exactly after 20 requests. There will be a small buffer.

Comment: I know about it. But what exactly I should set? 20KPerYear application level throttling? And generate token for a year in my case?

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will try your solution tomorrow.What about 20PerUser access without any time restrictions? (like in my question edit)

Comment: I don't think that's achievable with the current model.

Comment: Your workaround don't work for me :\ Please, see UPDATE in my question.

Comment: Working, added my SOLUTION to question.